# how to use jni in spark?

Tags: java-native-interface, apache-spark, java.library.path

I want to use jni to call my c++ lib in spark. When i sbt run my program, it shows that java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hq_Image_Process in java.library.path , so obviously the program can not find my hq_Image_Process.so .

In hadoop, -files can distribute the xxx.so file to the slaves like this:

```
[hadoop@Master ~]$ hadoop jar JniTest3.jar -files /home/hadoop/Documents/java/jni1/bin/libFakeSegmentForJni.so FakeSegmentForJni.TestFakeSegmentForJni input output
```

Are there any ways to call my hq_Image_Process.so like hadoop in spark?
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, the native library must be preinstalled on all worker nodes. Path to that library must be specified in `spark-env.sh`:

```
export SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/native/library
```

`SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND` environment variable might be used to diagnose it:

```
export SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND=1
```

If everything's set correctly, you will see output like this:

```
Spark Command:
/path/to/java -cp <long list of jars> -Djava.library.path=/path/to/native/library <etc>
========================================
```

Comment: hi wildfire,i distributed my libxxx.so to /usr/lib on every node. It seems everything is ok now. Thank you~

Comment: useful info if I need to distribute a model again

Comment: Is there any way to preinstall the library in all nodes automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Solution of accepted answer was for older (<1.0) Spark versions.

You need to set the following properties (either or both) on your `spark-defaults.conf`.

```
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath   /path/to/native/library
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath /path/to/native/library
```

The property keys are documented at [Configuration Section](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) of Spark docs.